# monitor http traffic from non-browser

Tags: http, traffic, web-server

I want to monitor http request generated out of a exe. Is there any tool that can help me?

Actually, an exe would call my asp.net web page to register a user. The exe constructs the request with all the data in it. when the request reaches my web page, I don't see any data. I wan to monitor the Request object and the traffic to find the reality.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks. Ananth

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look at the data being sent "over the wire", check out [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using MS IIS.
In IIS, you can enable logging in the Internet Services or IIS manager look at the website tab on website properties an enable logging. You can also customize what info gets logged. This should log HTTP requests regardless of where they originate from.

If you see browser-based requests but not traffic from your program, maybe look at debugging your program.

Comment: I have the code deployed in SI environment where I cant debug. But I was able to figure out that the same code works with UAT environment. I guess it has something to do with network. I will follow this with my network guys. 
Thanks for your input. Ananth